# Google analytics api - incomplete report batches

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So we have a working api that fetches reports at specific date ranges. Recently we tried to fetch reports with rows reaching up to 40,000 results. We got a response from the API and were able to extract the first 1000 rows.

Now the issue is with pagination. The query is set to retrieve 1,000 rows per batch thus a total of 40 batches ( based on the 40,000 rows). According the the [analytics api pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest), nextPageToken is retrieved from the api response and it is set to the next batch request. Most the time we are getting an incomplete report because the nextPageToken returned from the response is empty. Thus we cant proceed on fetching the next batch. We tried manually filling the [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#pagination) because it is a zero-based row index but the api call fails.

Any idea why the nextPageToken from the response randomly fails?

iteration code:

```
$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
$data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );

$cnt = 0; 
while ($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken > 0 && $cnt < 10) {
    \Log::info($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken); // Token log
    $body->reportRequests[0]->setPageToken($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
    $data =  $service->reports->batchGet( $body );
    showData($data->reports[0]->nextPageToken);
    $cnt++;
}

Log results:
Attempt 1
[2018-08-28 03:43:57] local.INFO: 1000  
[2018-08-28 03:43:59] local.INFO: 2000  
[2018-08-28 03:44:04] local.INFO: (failed/ empty next page token)
Attempt 2
[2018-08-28 03:45:01] local.INFO: 1000  
[2018-08-28 03:45:26] local.INFO: 2000  
[2018-08-28 03:45:42] local.INFO: (failed/ empty next page token) 
Attempt 3
[2018-08-28 03:48:47] local.INFO: 1000  
[2018-08-28 03:49:01] local.INFO: 2000  
[2018-08-28 03:49:15] local.INFO: 3000  
[2018-08-28 03:49:31] local.INFO: 4000  
[2018-08-28 03:49:46] local.INFO: 5000  
[2018-08-28 03:50:02] local.INFO: (failed/ empty next page token)  
Attempt 4
[2018-08-28 03:54:10] local.INFO: 1000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:12] local.INFO: 2000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:13] local.INFO: 3000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:14] local.INFO: 4000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:15] local.INFO: 5000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:16] local.INFO: 6000  
[2018-08-28 03:54:31] local.INFO: (failed/ empty next page token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to set each page token like `nextPageToken`

```
do {
   //your processing code
    $request->setPageToken($response[0]->getNextPageToken());//set next page token
} while ($response[0]->getNextPageToken() != '');
```

Comment: i was setting it(see sample code on the post). The problem lies on the $response[0]->getNextPageToken() is returning empty. I also tried manually setting if it returns empty since the nextPageToken is just an integer representing the index of the next batch, this approach also failed. So im thinking there might be an issue on google's end.